# Using repmat to create a dimension prior to the first dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hello I have a matrix A and I would like to repeat it 9 times in a new dimension that comes before all of A's dimensions. This is what I get:

```
>> A = rand(2,6,15,3,2);
>> R = repmat(A, [9 1 1 1 1 1]);
>> size(R)

ans =

    18     6    15     3     2
```

But I would like the size of R to be:

```
9 2 6 15 3 2
```

On a side note; I was able to add it to the end of A's dimensions and then I tried to reshape the matrix, but the entries got jumbed around.

Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it right!  You add each copy of `A` to the end as you said, then you need to do one extra step.

Make this a 6D matrix as you said in your post, stacking the 5D matrix in 9 slices, then [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) the dimensions.  As such:

```
A = rand(2,6,15,3,2);
R = repmat(A, [1 1 1 1 1 9]);
Rout = permute(R, [6 1 2 3 4 5]);
```

This should give you the desired result.

What the above code does is that it organizes the 5D slices so that each 5D matrix is indexed using the first dimension first, then it orders the other dimensions after that in order.  Doing `size` on `Rout` to double check gives:

```
size(Rout)

Rout = 

9    2    6    15    3    2
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes perfect sense! Thank you so very much rayryeng!

Comment: @user3784721 - You're welcome!  I think I answered this question very fast, so when the timer ends, please consider accepting my answer :)  Click on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left underneath the up and down voting arrows.  I've also voted up your post, so you should have enough reputation to up-vote my answer too if it helped :)

Comment: Awesome! It definitely helped and I appreciate you voting up my post!

Comment: @user3784721 - You're very welcome!  I've also upvoted the other post as well.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks again! What an awesome website, I am so excited that there is something like this out there. It is so much better than banging my head against the computer!!

Comment: @user3784721 - Haha! You're very welcome. One of my hobbies is actually answering StackOverflow questions. I have probably 10+ years experience in MATLAB and I used to be a part-time instructor at my university. It's nice to be able to still pay it forward where it counts.